# Convert prepareStament object to Json Scala

Tags: scala, jdbc, prepared-statement

I'am trying to convert prepareStament(object uses for sending SQL statement to the database ) to Json with scala.

So far, I've discovered that the best way to convert an object to Json in scala is to do it with the net.liftweb library. 
But when I tried it, I got an empty json. 
this is the code

```
import java.sql.DriverManager
import net.liftweb.json._
import net.liftweb.json.Serialization.write
object Main {
  def main (args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    implicit val formats = DefaultFormats

    val jdbcSqlConnStr = "sqlserverurl**"
    val conn = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcSqlConnStr)
    val statement = conn.prepareStatement("exec select_all")

    val piedPierJSON2= write(statement)
    println(piedPierJSON2)
  }
}
```

this is the result

`{}`

I used an object I created , and the conversion worked.

```
    case class Person(name: String, address: Address)
    case class Address(city: String, state: String)
    val p = Person("Alvin Alexander", Address("Talkeetna", "AK"))
    val piedPierJSON3 = write(p)
    println(piedPierJSON3)
```

This is the result

```
{"name":"Alvin Alexander","address":{"city":"Talkeetna","state":"AK"}}
```

Comment: there are many solution better that plain JDBC when it comes to mapping Scala types to DB queries ( [Anorm](http://playframework.github.io/anorm/), Doobie, Slick, ...)

Answer (score 0):

I understood where the problem was, PrepareStament is an interface, and none of its subtypes are serializable...
I'm going to try to wrap it up and put it in a different class.